# Shader Editor Problem

Tags: modeling, texturing

I want to use the shader Editor to give my objects color / color gradients but the objects doesnt react to anything I do in the shader editor.Yes, I made a check at "use Nodes"

Comment: Are you sure that you're editing the material that is assigned to the object (have you selected the object)?

Comment: yes, im sure. j

Comment: Please attach the blend file so I can see the problem.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/10g112qrdiiu7h9/sittebr.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have deactivated the nodes for several materials, which is why the settings aren't applied. Click "Use Nodes" and it works.

[image]
Nodes are deactivated in the file. Notice that "Use Nodes" is gray.

[image]
Click on "Use Nodes" to activate

[image]
Changes are now being applied.

Comment: thank you, it worked

Comment: @NeedSomeHelp You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark next to it.